# Why does terminating a suspended (not resumable) service instance return Failed, yet it is terminated

Tags: biztalk, biztalk-2010

Why does terminating a suspended (not resumable) service instance report failed, yet it is terminated?

Using the Microsoft.BizTalk.Operations BizTalkOperations.TerminateInstance() on a "Suspended (resumable)" and a "Suspended (not resumable)" instance (a routing failure report)

Checking the return Microsoft.BizTalk.Operations.CompletionStatus, the suspended is "Succeeded", but the suspended not resumable returns "Failed"

Yet when I check in the BizTalk Admin and/or BizTalkOperations.GetServiceInstances(), both instances have gone!

So what is happening here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Non Resumable instance typically is associated with its resumable instance. You must have terminated the suspended (resumable) prior to its corresponding suspended (non resumable) instance as a result you get a failure on non resumable because it got terminated as part of resumable instance. This is same behavior as you see in Admin Console.